# PreparedStatement troubles in Java

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

This is my method:

```
 @Override
public void deleteOneRecord(String tableName, String id) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
   // Validate the parameters here.

   // String sql = "DELETE FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + column + "=" + value;
    String pKeyColumnName = "";
   // Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

    DatabaseMetaData dmd = conn.getMetaData();

    ResultSet rs = dmd.getPrimaryKeys(null, null, tableName);
    while(rs.next()){
        pKeyColumnName = rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
        System.out.println("PK column name is " + pKeyColumnName);
    }
    //String sql = "delete from " + tableName + " where " + pKeyColumnName + "=" + id;

    String sql2 = "delete from ? where ?=?";

    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
    pstmt.setString(1, tableName);
    pstmt.setString(2, pKeyColumnName);
    pstmt.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(id));

    pstmt.executeUpdate(); 
}
```

This is my test `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    DBStrategy db = new MySqlDBStrategy();
    db.openConnection("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/book", "root", "admin");
    System.out.println(db.findAllRecords("author", 0).toString());
    db.deleteOneRecord("author", "2");
    System.out.println(db.findAllRecords("author", 0).toString());
    db.closeConnection();

}
```

The db object works, open connection works, my find all records method works, 
then my `deleteOneRecord` blows up. I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''author' where 'author_id'=2' at line 1

Now my syntax hasn't changed, I was running this code as just a `Statement` no problem a few minutes ago, so I must be using `PreparedStatement` incorrectly somehow.

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: `?` is only used for column values not for column or table names..

Comment: You should concat it `"delete from "+tableName+" where "+pKeyColumnName+"=?"`

Comment: Thank you. I'm gonna update that now. let you know.

Comment: If the caller knows the table name, the caller should also know the PK column name, so make the caller provide that name, instead of wasting time querying the database for it. Performance will suffer badly, the way you do it (`getPrimaryKey()` is not cheap).

Comment: Thank you Satya. You are a hero in my book.

Comment: Andreas, the instructor wanted us to assume the caller did not know the PK.  But that's a nice thing for me to bring up in class. Thanks.

Comment: This may also produce... interesting results if getPrimaryKeys returns more than one record.

Comment: @KenClubok I thought Pk's were one and only one in a table, FK's sure tons, but I thought PK's were only one column per table.  Lots I have to learn.

Comment: Multicolumn PKs are especially common if you have parent-child relationships.  The child will typically have the PK column(s) of the parent, plus an additional one.

Comment: @KenClubok thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe you can use parameters for the table name or the column name.  You'll have to concatenate those into the string.  Depending on where they come from, be careful about SQL injection vulnerabilities!

Comment: that's what I was trying to avoid.  I suppose I can run validation on the one incoming table name to make sure its legit.

Comment: You can use regex to verify that the variables including nothing but legal characters for column and table names.

Comment: @Drewtang I guess, the way you're doing it, the `getPrimaryKeys()` call will find nothing if a bad table name is provided, so as long as you check for that (which you don't), you'd be safe.

Comment: Works now, Thank you Mr. Clubok.

Comment: just starting on database stuff in Java EE 7 this semester.  Andreas, if you have the time and could explain how I'd check for that I'd love to hear it.

Comment: If rs is empty, then the table didn't exist.  Or it exists, but has no PK.